# Google line chart: Show only selected time period?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

On my company's homepage we use a WP plugin called wpDataTables/wpDataCharts to show a number of tables and charts. On this [page](https://aialphalab.com/fund/backtest-af-fondens-strategi/) we use a Google Charts line chart to show the performance of an investment strategy and a comparable index from 2007 to 2019.

As the WP plugin only allows for light customization, we use the callback function to customize the chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){ 
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; } 
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[5] = function(obj){ 
        obj.options.chartArea = {left:80,right:0,top:30,width:'100%',height:'70%'};
        obj.options.focusTarget = ['category'];
    obj.options.hAxis.ticks = [{v: new Date(2008, 2, 15), f: '2008'}, {v: new Date(2009, 2, 15), f: '2009'}, {v: new Date(2010, 2, 15), f: '2010'}, {v: new Date(2011, 2, 15), f: '2011'}, {v: new Date(2012, 2, 15), f: '2012'}, {v: new Date(2013, 2, 15), f: '2013'}, {v: new Date(2014, 2, 15), f: '2014'}, {v: new Date(2015, 2, 15), f: '2015'}, {v: new Date(2016, 2, 15), f: '2016'}, {v: new Date(2017, 2, 15), f: '2017'}, {v: new Date(2018, 2, 15), f: '2018'}, {v: new Date(2019, 2, 15), f: '2019'}];
    obj.options.vAxis = {scaleType: 'log'}
    obj.options.vAxis.ticks = [{v: 50, f: '50%'}, {v: 100, f: '100%'}, {v: 250, f: '250%'}, {v: 500, f: '500%'}, {v: 1000, f: '1.000%'}, {v: 2000, f: '2.000%'}];
}
});
</script>
```

Let's say you invested in the strategy on 01-01-2010. In that case it would be interesting for you to see the performance of the investment strategy from 01-01-2010 and forward. As in on 01-01-2010 the value of the strategy and the index where both 100% and the chart only shows data from that date onwards.

Is it possible to make such a thing? It would require a field where the user picks a date and then the chart change to start on 100% by that date.

I hope the question makes sense. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Best,
Morten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show only a selected time period in your Google Chart, you can filter the data based on the user's date selection and dynamically update the chart.

```js
// Assume `originalData` is your original data set
let originalData = [
  // your original data
];

// HTML input field for date selection
// <input type="date" id="startDate" />

document.getElementById("startDate").addEventListener("change", function() {
  let selectedDate = new Date(this.value);
  let filteredData = originalData.filter((row) => {
    return new Date(row[0]) >= selectedDate;
  });

  // Reset first data point to 100%
  if (filteredData.length > 0) {
    filteredData[0][1] = 100;  // Assume the investment value is in column index 1
  }

  // Update the chart with filtered data
  obj.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(filteredData), obj.options);
});
```

Replace `originalData` with your data.